# How to SELECT a field from a LEFT JOIN'ed table/model with Django's ORM (1.11)

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-rest-framework

**Context:** Using Django Rest Framework, I've created a ModelViewSet.

---

With these models:

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    permalink = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='ClaimCollaborator', through_fields=('claim', 'user'), related_name='claims')
    # ...other fields

class ClaimCollaborator(models.Model):
    claim = models.ForeignKey(Claim, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access_project_only = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I'm trying to query `Claim` to LEFT JOIN `ClaimCollaborator` and bring back the `access_project_only` field. `ClaimCollaborator` is actually an intermediary model handling the ManyToMany relationship between claims and users (collaborators of the claim).

So far I have the following view (cut down for brevity):

```
class ClaimViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = serializers.ClaimSerializer
    lookup_field = 'permalink'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Claim.objects.filter(Q(author=self.request.user) | Q(claimcollaborator__user=self.request.user))
```

Serializer:

```
class ClaimSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Claim
        fields = ('url', 'permalink', 'author', 'deleted')
        lookup_field = 'permalink'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'permalink'},
        }
```

Listing produces this SQL:

```
SELECT "api_claim"."permalink", "api_claim"."author_id", "api_claim"."deleted" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "api_claimcollaborator" ON ("api_claim"."id" = "api_claimcollaborator"."claim_id") 
WHERE ("api_claim"."author_id" = 39 OR "api_claimcollaborator"."user_id" = 39)
```

So I'm getting the LEFT JOIN on "api_claimcollaborator" (ClaimCollaborator) just fine, but none of the fields. I've tried `.only(<claim fields>, 'claimcollaborator__access_project_only')` and `.selected_related('claimcollaborator')` on the query but this just produces errors (I can be more specific about my attempts if that's helpful - just let me know).

I'm guessing this isn't so straightforward because the table in question is used as a ManyToMany within the ORM? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show ClaimSerializer; it is the serializer that is responsible for determining what fields are present in the output. (Note also, you shouldn't be defining the `list` method itself; you should define `get_queryset` to return the queryset only.)

Comment: Hey - the ClaimSerializer just formats the output though right? The issue here is the field is not even appearing in the query output. I started with defining get_queryset() but figured I don't want to modify that query as it also handles other viewset methods (retrieve() etc) which don't need the extra field.

Comment: No, the serializer determines what fields are present in the output. If necessary it will query for them itself. First you need to make the output the way you want, then you can look into modifying the queryset to ensure it gets all the fields at once.

Comment: Ok - I have added the Serializer code. I understand how to get/format foreign keys, but no idea how I would grab a field from a LEFT JOIN'ed model in the serializer. Adding 'access_project_only' produces "ImproperlyConfigured at /claims
Field name `access_project_only` is not valid for model `Claim`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SlugRelatedField` on the serializer to indicate a field on a related model identified by a specific attribute.

```
class ClaimSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())
    claimcollaborator_set = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='access_project_only', read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Claim
        fields = ('url', 'permalink', 'claimcollaborator_set', 'author', 'deleted')
```

Comment: Aha, this is definitely progress. Now I'm getting the fields, thank you. 

The only issue now is that it's returning all the rows matching the claim (naturally!), e.g. [false, true, false, false] etc, but I only want a single row, i.e. it to filter on ClaimCollaborator's `user` with the current user ID. I guess I can do that with the queryset() parameter of the SlugRelatedField? Only problem is getting the userID in that context...

Comment: Also, is the postfixed `_set` on the fieldname `claimcollaborators_set` of significance? Seems so as it doesn't work if I rename it. Trying to find this in the docs to no avail...

Comment: Ok, did some digging and found the answer to all my questions. For other people reading: explanation of _set here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

As for the problem mentioned my first comment, I simply made the field a ClaimCollaboratorSerializer(many=True) rather than the slug field, which will list all collaborators and allow me to programmatically go through it to determine access_project_only for the right user.